# How to use a combo box to fill mutltiple field in a subform in MS-Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have a sub form in Access that allows a user to select records using check boxes. In addition to this sub form there is a combo box with a list of names.

Is it possible to select a few records using the check boxes and assign a name to them with a press of a button?

The button is called [assignButton] , the sub form is called [list subform] and the combo box is called [personCombo] .

This seems like a simple task, but I am unfamiliar with how the VBA for the button triggering this kind of action would be written?

[image: Here is an example of my form]

All records are bound to an existing table called "tbl_jobs" this table has the same amount of rows and columns as the subform in the screenshot

Comment: Would be helpful if you could add some code snippets or examples of the forms

Comment: Can you share your tables/queries structure on which your sub form is based?

Comment: Please take a look at the update I posted

Comment: That is essentially what my form looks like the "Available People" combo box is coming from just a table called "tbl_people"

Comment: Please be more specific.  "Assign a name" is not specific enough.  Do you mean for each of the selected records to have the Person_Name field populated with the named from the combobox?

Comment: Yes exactly, I meant to say assign a name of person from the combo box

Comment: The select column is bound to a the table "tbl_jobs"

Comment: How can this SQL statement update the specific rows selected with the specific name selected from the combo box?

Comment: @jbud does the new info I've posted help?

Comment: @CPerkins are you still able to help?

Comment: I apologize for not including all of the necessary details right away, I am very new to this site and have never asked a question about Access. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Execute an update statement like `"UPDATE tbl_jobs SET Person_Name = '" & PersonCombo & "' WHERE [Select] = True"`.  There are various ways to execute this statement, and you may want to include other conditions to consider existing/old jobs, etc.  Also, it is best to avoid column and table names that use either VBA or SQL reserved words, e.g. "Select".

Comment: There seems to be an issue, instead of passing the value (name of person) selected in the personCombo box is passes,  '" & personCombo & "'

Comment: Any idea why this may be happening, seems like a syntax issue

Comment: The SQL string was just an example.  It must necessarily be used in the proper context and/or updated to properly construct the string in a different context.  If you are unfamiliar with how to do that, it requires too much tutoring for this one question.  Sorry.  This isn't to penalize you as a beginner, but SO is primarily intended for focused, specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*:  The following code is only intended to illustrate how to update the subform rows, so it includes no error handling or other common process code.  Also notice that the SQL statement has no additional criteria in the WHERE clause, primarily because the question lacks the subform's actual RecordSource query and/or information about how the subform table is prepared and/or filtered for each time the form is loaded.

```
Private Sub AssignPerson_Click()
  Dim qry as QueryDef
  Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
    "UPDATE tbl_jobs SET Person_Name = [ParamName]" & _
    " WHERE [Select] = True")
  qry.Parameters("ParamName") = PersonCombo.Value
  qry.Execute

  Me.list_subform.Requery 'Ensure subform displays updated rows
End Sub
```

Really this question is borderline "Too broad" for Stackoverflow.  There are multiple ways to accomplish what you want, and your problem is one of design, coding *and* understanding. But in the end, this model code is rather simple and satisfies the basic requirements so I feel it not worth nitpicking.